# Does this function actually have any points of inflection?

Tags: calculus

In a calculus lecture we were given an example that follows:

Classify the local extrema of $f(x)$ = $e^-$$^x$$(x^2 + x + 1)$ and find any points of inflection.

so,   $f'(x)$ = $e^-$$^x$$(2-x)(x+1)$

hence stationary points are at $x=-1$ and $x=2$

$f''(x)$ = $e^-$$^x$$(x^2 - 3x - 1)$

Ignoring the working for local extrema, lets focus on the points of inflection:

To find points of inflection, we find when $f''(x)$ = $0$,

i.e. when $x^2 - 3x -1 = 0$

hence by completing the square we get $x = \frac{3 \pm \sqrt {13}}{2}$ are points of inflection.

$End$ $of$ $the$ $example$

This confuses me because neither $x = \frac{3 \pm \sqrt {13}}{2}$ are stationary points so how on earth can they be points of inflection?

I understand that if there is a point of inflection at $x = a$ then $f''(a) = 0$ but it doesn't make sense to work both ways.

If someone can clear this up for me that would be great!

Comment: Ok, inflection points are not stationary points.

Comment: if $x=a$ is a point of inflection, then $f'(a)$ = 0 doesn't it?

Comment: No, if $x=a$ is a point of inflection, then $f''(a)=0$.

Comment: but the derivative of $f(x)$ at $a$ is 0.

Comment: No, the derivative of $f(x)$ at $a$, i.e. $f'(a)$ can by anything. It can be $f'(a)<0, f'(a)=0$ or $f'(a)>0$ when $a$ is an inflection point.

Comment: Connor-- If you plug in $(3 \pm \sqrt{13})/2$ to the derivative $f'(x)=e^{-x}(2-x)(x+1)$ it isn't $0.$

Comment: @coffemath but im saying that it isn't an inflection point, I've looked at a graph of this function and I can't see any inflection points

Comment: Actually $f'(x)=-x(x-1)e^{-x},$ rather than your version. And $f''(x)=(x^2-3x+1)e^{-x}$ as in Dr. Graubner's answer, which using quadratic equation does have two roots, and concavity changes at each.

Answer (score 2):

To clear things up. For $f$ twice differentiable:

1. If $f'(x_0)=0$ then $x_0$ is called a critical point of $f$. You know nothing about $f''(x_0)$. It can be negative, positive or zero.
2. If $f''(x_1)=0$ then this is a necessary (but not sufficient condition, see comments below) for $x_1$ to be called an inflection point of $f$. You know nothing about $f'(x_1)$. It can be negative, positive or zero.

**But** there is a connection between $f'(x_0)$ and $f''(x_0)$ when $x_0$ is a critical point, that is $f'(x_0)=0$: if you also know the sign of $f''(x_0)$ then you can tell if you have a minimum or a maximum (or a saddle point) in the critical point $x_0$. Vice versa, if you know that $x_1$ is an inflection point, $f''(x_1)=0$, then there is **no** connection with $f'(x_1)$, it can be anything and is also irrelevant.

Comment: So no matter what, if $f''(a)$ = 0, then a is a point of inflection?

Comment: Isn't that clear from my answer?

Comment: yes it is but I was just making sure

Comment: Stef: Note that if $f(x)=x^4$ then $f''(x)=12x^2$ so $f''(0)=0,$ yet $0$ is not the $x$ coordinate of an inflection point since the concavity is positive on both sides of $0.$

Comment: sorry to keep going on, but if $f(x) = 11 + 12x - x^3$ and $f''(x) = -6x$, then $x=0$ is a point of inflection?

Comment: Connor: you must consider the sign of $f''$ on both sides of the point where $f''=0$ In the case of $f''=-6x,$ the signs are opposite on each side of $0$ so that $0$ is (the $x$ coordinate of) an inflection point.

Comment: @coffeemath Yes, you are right. Are you happy with the correction;

Comment: @Stef The correction is good, but why not add the stuff about checking the concavity near the root $x=c$ of $f''=0$, i.e. if different sign on each side of $c$ ("near" to $c$) then inflection, if same signs, then not inflection. [And of course there can be "wild" examples where $f''$ has wavering signs on either or both side of $c$ --- these don't usually come up in the simple problems given in intro calc.]

Comment: @coffeemath can you give any link of those wild examples for which $f''$ have wavering signs. I am curious to know

Comment: @EkaveeraKumarSharma I found that using $f(x)=x^5sin(1/x)$ (for nonzero $x$, $f(0)=0$) seems to be an example (the extra power on the $x$ makes the second derivative go to zero as $x \to 0,$ and the dominant term in the second derivative is $x \sin(1/x)$ which will cause the desired oscillation of sign in $f''$ near $0$ (on either side).